# Z3 Power Modulo Statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

Does Z3 have the ability to do power mod arithmetic? For instance, if I'm placing in expressions of the sort `x ** y % z`, is there a way to tell Z3 that it is this type of expression, similar to how python has the function `pow(x,y,z)`? My assumption is that would open up solving options (such as modular inverse).

Comment: Are you just asking if Z3 has special support for that kind of arithmetic? Or are you asking for solutions? If you are interested in proving unsatisfiability, you could provide Z3 some pow-mod rules as quantified formulas.

Comment: I guess the base of my question is is there a better way to input those statements? As input, they would take a very long time to return. Unfortunately I'm not smart enough on the math side (or coding side for that matter) to actually help with the problem myself. Sounds like the answer is that, for now, the way mentioned above is the correct way, regardless of how long it would take to finish.

Comment: Just because Z3 does not have specific support for pow-mod it does not mean that you cannot efficiently handle some problems involving pow-mod using Z3. But this may require some preprocessing and encoding tricks on your side. If you present a concrete example problem maybe we can discuss a concrete example solution.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting point. There isn't any particular support for this in Z3. What are the known techniques in this area?

Comment: I'm admittedly out of my element with understanding the techniques. Been many years since the math undergrad, but I recall some techniques at that time for simplifying those classes of problems. From what I can tell, powmod stated directly in Z3 is very resource intensive for solving.

Comment: For the forward direction of computing *x^y* (mod *z*) given *x* and *y*, modular exponentiation is very efficient and is usually done by repeatedly squaring *x* mod *z*, using the binary decomposition of *y* to build up *x^y* mod *z*.  The inverse problem of finding *y* given *x* and *z* is the discrete log problem, though, so it's difficult for Z3 or anyone else.